# How to speed up boot times?

Tags: boot

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 set up as dual boot, before, ubuntu boots up under 10 second (I think maybe 7 or lower). Now it boots up 30 seconds or more which is pretty annoying. The thing is I don't know what I did before this happened and I'm pretty new at ubuntu. I've googled haven't seen anything that works.

Here's the part of dmesg where it slows down.

```
[    2.696568] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.705096] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.798688] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0fca, idProduct=8004
[    2.798698] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=5, SerialNumber=3
[    2.798705] usb 2-1.3: Product: RIM Composite Device
[    2.798710] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Research In Motion
[    2.798716] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 00793DF3233817E4C372480545113986A36D4753
[   28.457346] Adding 4102140k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4102140k 
[   28.489449] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   28.518070] udevd[404]: starting version 175
[   28.789652] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   29.904464] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   29.904472] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   29.904477] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054f SystemIO conflicts with Region \SBGP 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   29.904481] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 2 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   29.904484] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   29.904486] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \SBGP 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   29.904488] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 2 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   29.904490] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   29.904491] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \SBGP 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   29.904493] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 2 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   29.904496] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   29.904497] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
```

I was told to use bootchart but I don't know how to read the results:

[Bootchart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIsBr.png)

Answer (score 2):

Don't defrag the SSD !!!!!!! The sub-10 second boot time you initially achieved suggests that you use an SSD. There is absolutely no need to defrag SSDs, just the opposite, it reduces the lifetime of the SSD and doesn't give any performance gains.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of I/O by plymouth and ureadahead. So, there are three possible reasons:

1. ureadahead was reprofiled in the last boot, normally you need 2 cold boot to measure accurately this.
2. You left bootchart activated. **You shouldn't**. bootchart normally slows down your boot time and it shouldn't be used to measure the boot time, but finding out what your system do at boot time. Disable it/remove it.
3. Your partition is highly fragmented (yes, ext4 **data** gets fragmented) and those seek times kill your boot. Run `sudo e4defrag /dev/sda1` (changing sda1 for your actual partition) and see how your system goes:

   ```
   e4defrag /dev/sda1 
   ext4 defragmentation for device(/dev/sda1)
   [27442/276583]/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_gstreamer0.10_gstreamer-0.10_gst-plugin-scanner.1000.crash:  100%    [ OK ]
   [27447/276583]/var/crash/_usr_lib_firefox_firefox.1000.crash:   100%    [ OK ]
   [27449/276583]/var/crash/_usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash:  100%    [ OK ]
   [27454/276583]/var/crash/_usr_lib_virtualbox_VirtualBox.1000.crash: 100%    [ OK ]

   Success:            [ 7/276583 ]
   Failure:            [ 276576/276583 ]
   ```

   The "Success"/"Failure" was due I ran the program without being root.

Comment: Just finished defraging and doing a cold boot, it was a little bit faster than before. Here's the new dmesg: http://www.filedropper.com/dmesg is this the fastest that it can go or can I still make it faster. Would love to have the sub-10 bootup times again.

Comment: @Mirage that depends what you consider fast. Maybe you could remove some programs from boot, etc. I just gave you some tips. There are thousand ways to get fastest boot times.

Comment: Adding 4102140k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4102140k this part is the one that slows down the bootup the most, how do I remove/fix it. this delays the bootup by 30 seconds.

Comment: Actually no, as you see in the bootchart the process that slows most your boot is the I/O waits (hard disk). It could be that your HD is failing or near to fail. Adding the swap just need a second to be added, the line previous to it also don't slow down anything. The bottleneck is in your hard drive. You should delete the ureadahead profiles and reboot couple of times.

Comment: So I did sudo rm /var/lib/ureadahead/pack and did a cold boot after that and it boot up 27 seconds. Did a couple of cold boots after that and it went back up to 38-40sec. Should I remove ureadahead completely?

Comment: No, you should figure out what is making ureadahead take so much time. I don't know how to do that stuff, thou. I answered your question about "how to make the boot faster" now "how to make ureadahead faster" is another question altogether.